# convert string to date in azure databricks SQL

Tags: databricks-sql

I have a table with a date column as string data type  when i try to retrive data by  converting it to date data type  getting  Null values instead of getting  date value

Example:
select cast(ColumnName as date) from TableName

existed data before  doing cast is '2022/08/22' after applying cast  got Null values

Comment: use `to_date` with format: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/to_date.html

Comment: even when i tried to used to_date  getting null values

Comment: `select to_date('2022/08/22', 'yyyy/MM/dd')` -> `2022-08-22`

Answer (score 0):

New to Databricks and a coworker just had this come up. Make sure the 'yyyy/MM/dd' is whatever format your date currently is. It appears to tell databricks what is what. We initially tried the format we wanted the date in and that returned all nulls.